# Julia issue : ERROR: UndefVarError: JacobiRec not defined

Tags: ubuntu, julia

I'm practicing codes of Julia in https://quantecon.org/ with Ubuntu, but stuck with the below error problem.

When I implemented some codes, an error message comes out, reading

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: JacobiRec not defined
```

I can't find how to fix it. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

I think switching `JacobiRec` to `jacobi_rec` should solve your problem. This fix was already pushed to https://github.com/QuantEcon/Expectations.jl (I assume this is what you are getting this error).

The issue is caused by a change in https://github.com/JuliaApproximation/FastGaussQuadrature.jl that happened last month.

Comment: thank you for the informative comment. But it's been a short time since i started github, so I'm not that comfortable with it. So can you tell me how to switch JacobiRec to jocobi_rec? I updated the packages you mentioned, but it does not get fixed yet..

Comment: currently (i.e. before Expectations.jl gets a new release) the simplest thing to do is to `add Expectations#master`.

Comment: I did as you said, but got another error message like this: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Suppressor :
 Suppressor log:
 ├─possible versions are: ...
 ├─restricted to versions 0.1 by InstantiateFromURL , ...
 │ └─InstantiateFromURL log:
 │   ├─possible versions are: ...
 │   └─InstantiateFromURL is fixed to version 0.5.0
 └─restricted by compatibility requirements with Compat to versions: ...
   └─Compat log:
     └─restricted to versions 3.13.0-3 by Expectations 
         └─Expectations is fixed to version 1.6.0

Comment: You have packages installed that have conflicting version restrictions. As a rule it is recommended to have a separate project environment for each project to avoid this problem. Have a look at https://bkamins.github.io/julialang/2020/05/18/project-workflow.html for an explanation (you can skip the end part which is more advanced) and https://bkamins.github.io/julialang/2020/05/11/package-version-restrictions.html (to understand how to diagnose such things).

Comment: I appreciate your explanation. What a great guy you are!!! Thank you!

Comment: I finally fix it! I created another project and added the updated package there. Then everything worked so nicely. I can't understand the whole procedure technically well, but I should dig more in your helpful git blog. Thanx again.

Comment: Great to hear and all the best exploring Julia.